# Babel 6, export .. from './file', syntax error

Tags: mocha.js, webpack, babeljs

I'm getting a syntax error on [link: this line](https://github.com/logary/logary-js/blob/01ddf0d6dd20d17abb77b83be936033d6f8b50e0/src/index.js#L5), but I don't understand why it's failing.

```
> mocha-webpack --webpack-config webpack-test.config.js --growl --colors --require source-map-support/register --watch ./test/*.js


ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: /Users/h/dev/haf/logary/vendor/logary-js/src/index.js: Unexpected token (5:7)
};

export Identity from './identity';

    at Parser.pp.raise (/Users/h/dev/haf/logary/vendor/logary-js/node_modules/babylon/index.js:1378:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/Users/h/dev/haf/logary/vendor/logary-js/node_modules/babylon/index.js:2817:8)
    at Parser.pp.expect (/Users/h/dev/haf/logary/vendor/logary-js/node_modules/babylon/index.js:2811:33)
```

I'm probably missing something. Babel preset is es2015. It's a pure lib, so no react preset needed. Removing this line makes it all work fine. Except of course that I'm not able to compose the lib in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the link you provided, it seems you wanted to do:

```
export { default as Identity } from './identity';
```